# Error in commit (github, egit)

Tags: git, github

I use egit for commit my project with my team.
But after push my project, all of our team's commit logs were gone.

[image]

And my team members cannot fetch.
I want rolling back my commit.

please help me

Comment: It would have been more helpful to simply link to your github repository instead of the screenshot.  Here is the link, https://github.com/youjin9209/2015_software_engineering

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your `test_view` branch.  Are the missing commits there?

https://github.com/youjin9209/2015_software_engineering/tree/test_view

It looks like you may have accidentally pushed a new `master` branch.  You may (or may not) want to delete that branch.  Also, this `master` branch is the default branch of your repository.  The default branch is the one that shows up by default in GitHub's web UI, among other things.

You can either delete that master branch on github, or you can change the settings for that repository to make the `test_view` branch the default branch.  I'd recommend changing the default branch, if everybody else is using `test_view` as their main branch.

Comment: I checked the test_view's commit log, but it remained just 37 commit.

Comment: How can I delete the master branch? and if I delete it, are all of the last work gone??

Comment: you can delete the `master` branch using the command `git push origin :master` or by using the github UI.  I don't think the github UI will allow you to delete the "default" branch, however.  You should first edit the settings and make `test_view` the new "default" branch, and then you can use the GitHub UI to delete the `master` branch